# Hiding parent elements with no li children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angular

I am trying to hide the main heading when there is no child `<li>` element. I used this `if` condition:

```
if($(".sportsUlLi").length){
```

However even when no `<li>` element is generated it's not hiding the parent `<div>` with class `sports`.

```js
if ($(".sportsUlLi").length) {
  console.log("sports length--->" + $("sportsUlLi").length);
  $(".sports").hide();
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default sports headingBorderNone">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a href="javascript:;" class="panelPlanelTitle" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="fa fa-caret-right  panelCaret"></i>
        sports
      </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="sports" class="panel-collapse collapse panelPlanelData">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <ul class="sportsUl">
        <li class="sportsUlLi" *ngFor="let sportsVal of sportsList" (click)="Planels($event)" [attr.id]="sportsVal.id" >{{sportsVal.name}}</li>
        <!--<li  class="recentList" [routerLink]="['/UARsportsPlanel']"><span>UAR sports Planel</span></li> -->
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(".sportsUlLi").length == 0`?

Comment: Have you tried `if($(".sportsUlLi").length<1){`

Comment: hey but still it didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use non-jQuery style hiding of the `div` either using `ngIf` or using the `hidden` property like this,

```
<div class="panel panel-default sports headingBorderNone" *ngIf="sportsList.length > 0">
  ...
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="panel panel-default sports headingBorderNone" [hidden]="sportsList.length === 0">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: thanks it worked...i am new to angular 2...can you tell me what does sportsList means...if you explain it would be great so that in future I can make changes by myself

Comment: `sportsList` is an ‘array’ object that is defined in your ‘component’ file likely as `this.sportsList = <some-kind-of-an-array>;`

Answer (score 0):

`$(".sportsUlLi").length` return integer not bool. Use like this.

```
 if($(".sportsUlLi").length == 0){
        console.log("sports length--->" + $("sportsUlLi").length);
        $(".sports").hide();
}
```